# curl: about `--install-dir` option

Tags: curl, composer-php

I'm running this command:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=~/bin
```

but I get this:

> All settings correct for using Composer. The defined install dir
>   (~/bin) does not exist.

but, since I have that directory created, why am I getting that error?

Comment: the `--install_dir` option is a switch you're passing to php, not curl

Comment: but `--` by itself generally terminates options lists.

Comment: it sounds like it's passing the option to the php code which in turn is throwing the error

Comment: what do you get if you run `ls ~/bin -la`?

Comment: @TimTisdall `drwxrwxr-x  2 tirengarfio pg5978157   24 oct 23 09:03 .
drwx--x--- 10 tirengarfio adm       4096 oct 23 09:39 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 tirengarfio pg5978157   22 oct 23 09:03 php -> /usr/local/bin/php-5.3`

Comment: have you tried using an absolute path?  `/home/tirengarfio/bin` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess the answer is that `~` isn't expanded into the user's home directory.